# Boxplot outlier values into a table

Tags: r, outliers

I was wondering how I could go about trying to take outliers from Boxplot$out (returns the outliers within the data) and put them into a table which shows the class they belong to e.g. if outlier is from class "Van", "Bus, "Saab" etc..

I have tried using which() function but this returns only the index of the outlier and not the class. I am not sure how to go about putting this into a table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
library(reshape2)
vehData <-
  structure(
    list(
      Samples = 1:6,
      Comp = c(95L, 91L, 104L, 93L, 85L,
               107L),
      Circ = c(48L, 41L, 50L, 41L, 44L, 57L),
      D.Circ = c(83L,
                 84L, 106L, 82L, 70L, 106L),
      Rad.Ra = c(178L, 141L, 209L, 159L,
                 205L, 172L),
      Pr.Axis.Ra = c(72L, 57L, 66L, 63L, 103L, 50L),
      Max.L.Ra = c(10L,
                   9L, 10L, 9L, 52L, 6L),
      Scat.Ra = c(162L, 149L, 207L, 144L, 149L,
                  255L),
      Elong = c(42L, 45L, 32L, 46L, 45L, 26L),
      Pr.Axis.Rect = c(20L,
                       19L, 23L, 19L, 19L, 28L),
      Max.L.Rect = c(159L, 143L, 158L, 143L,
                     144L, 169L),
      Sc.Var.Maxis = c(176L, 170L, 223L, 160L, 241L, 280L),
      Sc.Var.maxis = c(379L, 330L, 635L, 309L, 325L, 957L),
      Ra.Gyr = c(184L,
                 158L, 220L, 127L, 188L, 264L),
      Skew.Maxis = c(70L, 72L, 73L,
                     63L, 127L, 85L),
      Skew.maxis = c(6L, 9L, 14L, 6L, 9L, 5L),
      Kurt.maxis = c(16L,
                     14L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 9L),
      Kurt.Maxis = c(187L, 189L, 188L, 199L,
                     180L, 181L),
      Holl.Ra = c(197L, 199L, 196L, 207L, 183L, 183L),
      Class = c("van", "van", "saab", "van", "bus", "bus")
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,
                  6L), class = "data.frame")

#Remove outliers 
removeOutliers <- function(data) {
  OutVals <- boxplot(data)$out
  remOutliers <- sapply(data, function(x) x[!x %in% OutVals])
  return (remOutliers)
}
 
vehDataRemove1 <- vehData[, -1]
vehDataRemove2 <- vehDataRemove1[,-19]
vehData <- vehDataRemove2
vehClass <- vehData$Class

boxplot(vehData)
#Begin removing outliers
removeOutliers1 <- removeOutliers(vehData)
removeOutliers2 <- removeOutliers(removeOutliers1)
```

Comment: This command `idx <- sapply(length(OutVals$out), function(x) which(vehData[, OutVals$group[x]] == OutVals$out[x]))` will get you the index values of the outliers, BUT it will only work reliably with integer values. For decimal values you will have to search for values near the outlier (e.g. abs(diff) < .00001).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! All my data are integers so I should be fine trying and using this method?

Comment: @dcarlson I get the error:  Error in OutVals$out : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors. When placing this under "OutVals <- boxplot(data)$out" in my removeOutliers function

Comment: You need more than just the outliers so do not use `OutVals <- boxplot(data)$out`, use `OutVals <- boxplot(data)'. You are throwing away the information about which group the outlier came from.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I noticed I was doing this! While, I didn't do boxplot(data) I done attrib <- boxplot(OutVals). However, when I tried getting the groups and the name of the groups using attrib$names or attrib$group. The names returned were in numbers e.g. "1", "2", etc.. and not based on my original data's classes e.g. "Van", "Bus" etc.. Would you know how I could fix this problem? So it displays the class of the outlier alongside the outlier itself? I am hoping to put this into a data frame.

Answer (score 1):

This can be simplified. Starting with your data frame `vehData`. First get the rownumbers of the outliers. In my comment I accidentally left out the `seq()` function:

```
vehDataRemove <- vehData[, -c(1, 20)]
OutVals <- boxplot(vehDataRemove)
idx <- sapply(seq(length(OutVals$out)), function(x) which(vehDataRemove[, OutVals$group[x]] == OutVals$out[x]))
idx
# [1] 5 5 6 5 3
```

Notice that three outliers are in the 5th row. Now remove the rows with outliers:

```
NoOuts <- vehDataRemove[-unique(idx), ]
NoOuts
#   Comp Circ D.Circ Rad.Ra Pr.Axis.Ra Max.L.Ra Scat.Ra Elong Pr.Axis.Rect Max.L.Rect Sc.Var.Maxis Sc.Var.maxis Ra.Gyr Skew.Maxis Skew.maxis Kurt.maxis Kurt.Maxis Holl.Ra
# 1   95   48     83    178         72       10     162    42           20        159          176          379    184         70          6         16        187     197
# 2   91   41     84    141         57        9     149    45           19        143          170          330    158         72          9         14        189     199
# 4   93   41     82    159         63        9     144    46           19        143          160          309    127         63          6         10        199     207
```

So you have lost half of your data! Alternatively set the outliers to missing values:

```
Outs2NA <- vehDataRemove
Outs2NA[cbind(idx, OutVals$group)] <- NA
Outs2NA
#   Comp Circ D.Circ Rad.Ra Pr.Axis.Ra Max.L.Ra Scat.Ra Elong Pr.Axis.Rect Max.L.Rect Sc.Var.Maxis Sc.Var.maxis Ra.Gyr Skew.Maxis Skew.maxis Kurt.maxis Kurt.Maxis Holl.Ra
# 1   95   48     83    178         72       10     162    42           20        159          176          379    184         70          6         16        187     197
# 2   91   41     84    141         57        9     149    45           19        143          170          330    158         72          9         14        189     199
# 3  104   50    106    209         66       10     207    32           23        158          223          635    220         73         NA          9        188     196
# 4   93   41     82    159         63        9     144    46           19        143          160          309    127         63          6         10        199     207
# 5   85   44     70    205         NA       NA     149    45           19        144          241          325    188         NA          9         11        180     183
# 6  107   57    106    172         50       NA     255    26           28        169          280          957    264         85          5          9        181     183
```